# CORS/REST URI limit?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, wcf, rest, cors

I'm trying to enter data into a table using REST (WCF CORS) call from an ASP.NET page via jquery/javascript. The initial call works perfectly. Once I get the record key, i know the call is good, and I fire a toast message that indicates such, then i clear the text boxes to allow another re-entry.

On the second entry, once the info is filled out and passes validation. I get this error in Chrome

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'localhost' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

[image] - You can see the first call is succesfully, but then the 2nd fails with the above error. It seems i have CORS set up correctly since i'm able to make the initial call successfully. I've even tried a redirect, and it only works for the first entry. In order to get another successful post I must 'physically' refresh the page, then reenter that data.

Any ideas here? Thanks in advance!

<s>*UPDATE*: this only appears to be an issue in Chrome v 38.02.2125.111. IE 11.0.9600 works fine.</s>

UPDATE 2: this appears to be an issue with the URL length.... i think...

UPDATE 3: it appears there is a 310 character limit for URIs?  Anyone know how to get around that?

Comment: If you're POSTing(?) why the query string?

Comment: @EdSF - That is the only way i could get it to work. I'm sending a JSON (stringify) object. Then deserializing to my VB.NET object in my WCF. I'm looking into other ways to doing this like ASP.NET WEB API, but i need a work around for this until I can figure that out. It appears the REST/WCF isn't working out like i had hoped.

Comment: Understood, but you are POSTing, not sending it via GET (data in the latter via querystring, the former in request body) - so your URL wouldn't have a query string (at all).

Comment: perhaps i'm not understanding... if u look the screenshot where the POST happens (the successful one at the top), u can see the JSON embedded in the URL. I have found that if the TOTAL URL string is 311 characters it fails. 310 or under works.

Comment: I'm getting the sense that how i'm passing my JSON object isn't the correct way as I can't for the life of me thing of why there would be a 310 character limit........

Comment: i confirm jharris8567's comment

the API will not be recognized anymore when it goes beyond the URI limit causing it to throw CORS issue